# Shortcode do not return a value

Tags: shortcode

Just wondering, why shorcode do not return a value.
Here is an example.

```
    add_shortcode( 'terms', 'x_get_custom_terms' );

    function x_get_custom_terms( $atts, $content = null ) {

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'include'    => '',
            'show_count' => false
        ), $atts, 'terms' );


        $terms = get_terms($atts);
        $items = '';

        if( !empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms) ):
            foreach($terms as $term):
                $items .= sprintf('<li class="cat-item cat-item-%d">
                                    <a href="%s">%s</a> %s</li>',
                    $term->term_id, 
                    get_term_link($term->term_id),
                    esc_attr($term->name),
                    $atts['show_count'] ? "($term->count)" : '');
            endforeach;
            return sprintf('<ul class="categories">%s</ul>', $items);
        endif;
            return false;
    }
```

This shortcode returns list of terms, just the same as default category widget do, but this one uses different taxonomies. I return result in string format (or I think so). If I `echo` result of this function for testing purposes - I see terms list, if I try to return this list - no result.

Comment: Seems like you are missing `'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'` $atts that is passed to get_terms, check [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) for more options

Comment: get_terms works well with include attribute without taxonomy (already tested). So, if I write `echo` instead of `return` - I will see ul list with different terms from different taxonomies, but with return - I see nothing.

Comment: try creating a variable that will contain `sprintf('<ul class="categories">%s</ul>', $items)`, something like `$res = sprintf('<ul class="categories">%s</ul>', $items)`, than return the variable.

Comment: Doesn't work similarly)

Comment: the code seems to output ok in my test site; maybe there are interfering plugins or other filters in your site?

Comment: Nope, clean theme for testing purposes and just wpbakery pagebuilder (tried to deactive it). So in your installation `[terms include="comma separated term ids"]` work with just return?